# react native using asyncStorage for daily journaling and charting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, asyncstorage

I'm creating a prototype app for a client and it's mainly concerned with self journaling and graphing. Say I wanted to enter how many calories I ate today and how many calories I burned, I would have a screen with two inputs where I could save those numbers for myself along with today's date.

I'm wondering how I can use asyncStorage like this with the date so that any user can have the data specific to their device/phone and they can journal every day but I can use the data (by date) to show on a graph for them. Basically, if they saved calories in/calories out every day for a week the graph would be able to show the data for each day of that week on their device.

I have a very basic example of that here:

```
async storeItem(key, item) {
try {
    var jsonOfItem = await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(item));
    return jsonOfItem;
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message);
}
}
```

But how can I do this with keys like 'caloriesIn' and 'caloriesOut' as well as the current date with each?

Answer (score 0):

React Native has lots of options for storing data here are some of the options:

1. RealM
2. Vasern
3. Firebase
4. SQlite
5. PouchDB
6. AsyncStorage
7. Watermelon DB

From all of this, I think for your case [react-native-sqlite-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sqlite-storage) should be a better choice as it will let you query the data by date.

Comment: Is that local to their phone? I'm trying to make a fairly simple Journaling app that's cross platform, will the one you linked be locally stored on their phone?

Comment: yes, it is stored locally internally it uses the builtin SQLite solution provided by the OS.